# Get name from file input

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I upload my file image this `!$this->upload->do_upload($name)` will not work.

It is not picking up my field `name="banner_image[ + image_row + ]['image']"`

The image_row generates the row id number.

**Var dump**

```
array(1) { ["banner_image">=> array(5) { ["name">=> array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["image">=> string(10) "10-dec.jpg" } } ["type">=> array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["image">=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } } ["tmp_name">=> array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["image">=> string(24) "C:\Xampp\tmp\phpC1F6.tmp" } } ["error">=> array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["image">=> int(0) } } ["size">=> array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["image">=> int(261032) } } } }
```

**On the controller do_upload function how can I make it pick up field name correct?**

**Controller function**

```
function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '3000';
    $config['max_width']  = '*';
    $config['max_height']  = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    // this below is same as whats on set_rules 
    $name = "banner_image[' + image_row + '][image]"; // + image_Row + is id as shown on view

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($name)) {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;

    } else {

        return true;

    }
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;


function addImage() {
  html = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
  html += '<td class="text-left">';
  <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
  html += '<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">';
  html += '<span class="input-group-addon"><img src="<?php echo base_url("image/flags");?>/<?php echo $language["image"]; ?>"></span><input type="text" name="banner_image[' + image_row + '][banner_image_description][<?php echo $language["language_id"]; ?>][title]" value="" placeholder="Name Of Banner" class="form-control" />';
  html += '</div>'; 
  <?php } ?>  
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td class="text-left">';
  html += '<input type="text" name="banner_image[' + image_row + '][link]" value="" placeholder="Website Page Url" class="form-control" />';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td class="text-left">';
  html += '<div class="imagePreview" class="img-thumbnail"></div>';
  html += '<input id="idFile" type="file" name="banner_image[' + image_row + '][image]" onchange="previewImage(this,[256],4);" />';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td class="text-left">';
  html += '<input type="text" name="banner_image[' + image_row + '][sort_order]" value="" placeholder="Sort Order" class="form-control">';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td class="text-left">';
  html += '<button type="button" onclick="$(\'#image-row' + image_row  + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('#images tbody').append(html);
  image_row++;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refer the Codeigniter Userguide File upload class.  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

You have used **text** type input in the form. Use **file** type input. Just giving an option.

Anyways the link will walk you through a simple file uploading exercise.

To get the file name of the uploaded file you can use this in the controller.
$filename = $this->upload->data('file_name');

Then from controller you can send it to any model.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this change this line

```
name="banner_image[ + image_row + ]['image']"
```

to

```
name="banner_image[ '+ image_row +' ]['image']"
```

you missed `''`

and in script

```
html = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
```

to

```
html += '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
```

Comment: No did not work it stop me from adding row. Still keeps on saying You did not select a file to upload.